# Why did I get blurry star trails?

Tags: night, photography-basics, stars

This is my first star trail photograph stacked with StarStaX and can't seem to find out why they are so blurry.

[image]

I have a sturdy metal tripod with a cable release and shined a light to focus on the foreground beforehand. The image is at f/4 aperture, 30 second shutter speed, ISO 250, with a 24 mm focal length and manual focus on. Any advice would be helpful and don't be afraid to ask for any other pictures to help me figure this out.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

> shined a light to focus on foreground beforehand

If you focused on the foreground then the most likely explanation is that the stars are blurry because they are out of focus, at f/4 the depth of field is not sufficient to contain both the foreground and the stars (which are effectively at "infinity" or as far away as you can get).

I would recommend you try to manually focus on the stars themselves, this is difficult as they are so dim, even with live-view and high ISO settings. The best approach is to attempt to focus as best you can, shoot a short trails exposure, check focus on the rear LCD at maximum magnification, if it's repeat those steps and keep going until you nail the focus.

Comment: You could also try using manual focus and focusing to infinity

Comment: @laurencemadill Very few lenses focus accurately to infinity when set to infinity.

Comment: If the moon is around, focus on that. Otherwise something far on the horizon could work too.

Comment: @chili555 oh ok, I'd never really tried; I have to rely entirely on autofocus because I can't see focus properly when I try to use manual focus

Comment: Thanks everyone for the advice now if I used a bigger aperture NUMBER with a longer shutter speed would that be easier to focus and/or give me a better outcome or should I just keep it at 4, im looking for a night without the moon for less residual light, and my lens doesnt have a symbol that says infinity like ive seen do I just turn it all the way clockwise .also I did many test shots but didnt even think to check the focus at 100%. ill pay closer attention to these details next time.

Comment: @chili555 very few modern lenses focus accurately to infinity. Older professional lenses (like many manual focus Nikkor AI or AI-s lenses) have infinity stops so accurate that they are good enough for laboratory use and temperature stable too. It's quite unfortunate we lost that. That being said, he needs to focus at hyperfocal distance, not infinity, which is rather difficult to do with lenses that lack focus scales (or when the focus scale is not precise enough).

Comment: @AramHăvărneanu As a matter of fact, my favorite wide field astro lens is a Nikon 28mm f/2 AI.

Comment: @chili555 I don't have that lens, but I have many other wide and normal manual focus Nikkor lenses and I would expect your lens to be excellent too. If you find out that the infinity hard stop does not achieve perfect focus, I would recommend to recalibrate the lens. Btw, how is coma at f/2 with that lens?

Comment: @AramHăvărneanu I have no complaints. The hard stop is perfect and the coma is a tiny bit greater than I wish and so I generally crop it out.